# Is there a chemical reaction that blocks two cysteines by reacting with a third molecule?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, organic-chemistry

The idea is to block the two cysteines so they can't react in the future. We need the reaction to remove the -SH groups of the two cysteines, or modify them.

Also important, the reaction should not make cross-link between the two cysteines.

[image: bi-Cysteine -SH group passivation reaction. Ideas for an adapted chemical ?]

To explain briefly my motivation: I am a PhD student and I do optical tweezer experiments. We can hold and manipulate two micrometer beads in two optical traps. We have a process to tether one protein using two DNA linkers to the two beads. I need to block two of the three cysteines of my trimer to properly couple the protein to both beads.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, I've voted to close this question because it is primarily about chemistry rather than biology. While this might be a better fit for [Chemistry.SE], please don't repost (instead request migration). ———— In addition, we encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). I would start by looking into peptide synthesis. Thanks! 